# Linq group join is not creating Hierarchy

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I need to fix following Linq in a way it returns me

```
     Class Result 
    {
        int factoryId;
        string Name,
        string address,
        List<Image> Images

    }
```

If i remove "group into" it gives me flat results back. if i add group into it throws exception saying invalid column photo_2. There is no such column in my class.

```
      var context= new MyContext();
        var data = from fac in context.Factory
            join prod in context.FactoryProducts on fac.factoryId equals Prod.factoryId
            join prodsample in context.ProductSample on fac.factoryId equals prodsample.factoryId
            join img in context.CatalogImages on img.PhotoId equals prodsample.PhotoId into img
                   where fac.factoryId == 001

            select new
            {
                fac.factoryId,
                fac.Name,
                fac.address,
                Images=img

            };
```

Comment: so do you mean the ***posted*** code throws the exception `invalid column photo_2`? Looks like accessing to `CatalogImages` throws that exception. And it may be some wrong mapping to database in your configuration.

Comment: I'm not familiar with query syntax but it looks a bit strange at `where fac.factoryId == 001` (I think this should be placed at the first place). Also the `img` is used for both running variable and for the `into` clause, which I believe would not even compile. Also the `join prod in context.FactoryProducts on fac.factoryId equals Prod.factoryId` is redundant. However you talked about the exception `invalid column photo_2` which is strange. It's normally a sign of wrong configuration (to map tables).